# Solr - Range facets are not working as expected

Tags: solr, solrj, solrcloud

I am trying the range facet on a field called popularity .

facet=true&facet.range=popularity&facet.range.gap=1&facet.range.start=1&facet.range.end=5.001

I am getting the below result

"popularity":{
        "counts":[
          "1.0",3,
          "2.0",0,
          "3.0",8,
          "4.0",21,
          "5.0",23],

But when I am adding the filter query - fq=popularity:[3 TO 4} , I am getting 11 results, I see all the results are having popularity between 3 to 4, but why when faceting on popularity it is under counting the items ?

Thanks

Comment: What is the field type of the `popularity` field?

Comment: @MatsLindh - its tdouble . [solr.TrieDoubleField]

Comment: Possible guess: the `precisionStep` setting ends up creating tokens (multiple terms) that fubar the range faceting. You could try setting precisionStep to 64 as that would only generate a single term for each field (or see if the more modern Point version of doubles work better).